# used a 'next' branch to publish my next version, now how do i merge it to master with semantic-release

Tags: git-branch, semantic-release

I created a 'next' branch to release the 'next' version of my package to npm.  which i think is a pretty darn cool feature of semantic-release.  However, now I'm a bit unclear on what I need to do to properly move that over to my master branch to ensure it now becomes the 'latest' tag?  Can I do this without cutting a new release and just update the tag?  Or is there some other magical semantic-y way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you use semantic-release version 16.0.0 (currently in beta) you would have to merge the `next` branch into the `master` branch. semantic-release will take care of making the version available on `@next` dist-tag to `@latest`.

Be aware that this merge has to preserve the Git tags and if you use the GitHub "Rebase and Merge" is won't be the case as each commit will be rewritten.

Comment: so you will have to merge to master to create a pre release??

Comment: No. You merge to create a new release on master.